# Haskell Array Subtraction

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to brush up on my Linear Algebra skills and am also learning Haskell and thought...why not learn by doing one on the other! (Two birds one stone)

```
-- Vector

a = [1,0,0]
b = [2,0,4]

subTwoLists (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x-y) : (subTwoLists xs ys)
```

What I'd really like to understand:

- `(x:xs)` and `(y:ys)`  :  Do these just mean for all elements in a and all elements in b?
- `= (x-y)` : Should compute `a[0] - b[0] = c[0]`, right?

Comment: poor birds... not a vegan post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with this code:

```
subTwoLists :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
subTwoLists (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x-y) : (subTwoLists xs ys)
```

You are not handling the base case. In recursion, you always have to 
handle the base case. Something like this should work:

```
subTwoLists :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
subTwoLists [] _ = []
subTwoLists _ [] = []
subTwoLists (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x-y) : (subTwoLists xs ys)
```

> Do these just mean for all elements in a and all elements in b?

Yes. But Why don't you try it yourself in ghci?

> (x-y) : Should compute a[0] - b[0] = c[0] right?

Yes.

Also, note that you are using `Lists`, not arrays.

Comment: Thank you!  
What does this accomplish ? :
subTwoLists :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]

Comment: @Genesis It's a type signature telling that the function `subTwoLists` accepts two lists as input and gives one list as output. Usually, writing type signature is not mandatory but it helps a lot while reading the code.

Comment: [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] Would this accept 3 lists and output a list?

Comment: @Genesis: you don't have to write the function on your own - there is a nice HOF doing it for you: [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith): `subTwoLists = zipWith (-)` ;)

Comment: @Carsten That's nicer!

Comment: Since the OP is using this in linear algebra, the OP is only calling `subTwoLists` with same-length lists. If by mistake lists are not of the same length, then `subTwoLists` will silently truncate the longer list so to make them even. If this is undesired, and the OP would prefer a runtime error instead, one can return `error "uneven lists"` instead of `[]` in the first two equations.